What is the best way to convert a 1.2-4.5 vdc signal to a 0-5 vdc signal?
I have a 1.2-4.5vdc output from a hall sensor throttle control and I need 0-5vdc signal for the input of a bldc motor controller.  I'm not sure of the input signal current needs of the controller.  I do not have this data available to me.  My best estimate is 20mA would be the highest possible value.
I just learned these words, but gain and offset with op-amp and voltage divider sound good, but which op amp, and how to set it up?

This might be useful for solving your problem: https://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa030a/sloa030a.pdf

As already mentioned by @Velvet, you need to subtract 1.2V and then you need to add some gain.
Something like below can do the job.


What supply voltage do you have available? If just 5V you need to use a rail-to-rail op-amp. If higher like 12V you can use a common op-amp.
Btw, you need to decrease the signal -0.35V first, then amplify it x1.2 around middle (2.5V).

Your solution will convert 1.2V ... 4.5V to 1V ... 5V (see https://i.sstatic.net/KnFAusbG.png). Instead, you want to subtract 1.2V and then amplify by 5/3.3 (see https://i.sstatic.net/9hWVZJKN.png).

@Velvet I thought about amplification around 2.5V. But your solution is also possible.
